# excel formula to counta based on header value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to count the number of cells with content in them, the way COUNTA() does, based on the header value. This way I want a formula in a sheet that sees in this same sheet a reference, then look in another sheet another cell that matches - located in the first row, where the headers are - this reference and finally uses COUNTA() in the values below the header. I want the formula to look for the location of the column where I want the COUNTA() to work.
I am not sure if I can do this without VBA, I was really hoping to find a formula that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX() to return the correct range:

```
=COUNTA(INDEX(A:E,0,MATCH(G3,1:1,0)))-1
```

The -1 deals with the Header.

[image]

INDIRECT and OFFSET are volatile so use INDEX which is not.

Comment: This works fine when everything is in the same sheet. However, I can't make it work when the database and the reference are in different sheets. I am pretty sure it takes just a little tweek to make it work, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Put the sheet name in front of the references.  ie if they were on `Sheet1`: `=COUNTA(INDEX(Sheet1!A:E,0,MATCH(G3,Sheet1!1:1,0)))-1`

Comment: Of course! I was forgetting about the second match variable. Thank you very much...